# Encode column in kendo grid ui when export excel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-dataviz

use Html.Raw in kendo grid using .Encode(false) in column. But then export to excel not remove html tag.

```
@(Html.Kendo()
      .Grid<SuggestionsJsonModel>()
      .Name("Grid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(p => p.Suggestion).Title("Title").Encoded(false);
      })
```

[result: view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2rRW.jpg)

```
.Excel(excel => excel.FileName("SuggestionReport.xlsx")
          .Filterable(true)
          .ProxyURL(Url.Action("ExcelExportSave", "SuggestionManagement"))
          .AllPages(true))
      .ToolBar(tb => tb.Excel()
          .Text("Excel Export"))
```

[Problem in Export Excel: view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kt0D.jpg)